# Spring autowire Bean again on each call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing framework used for E2E frontend testing using primarily Selenium's WebDriver and I would like to add Spring framework to it. Got some issues regarding WebDriver object, let me explain:

Whenever I need current WebDriver instance I use this method:

```
 public class DriverManager {
 (...)
//@Bean //For further explanation
 public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    return getOrCreateWebDriver();
}
 (...)
}
```

As written above, It will create WebDriver object if it is `null` (meaning, was not even once initialized or was disposed (`quit` method called) ) or return existing instance. This method is used **ALL ACROSS** the framework and always retrieve correct WebDriver instance. This method was previously `static` and now, introducing Spring, it is refactored as instance.

I could `@Autowired` DriverManager instance almost everywhere and just call `getWebDriver` but I'm looking for better solution.

Ideally I would like to achieve something like this:

```
    @Scope("singleton")
    public class SingletonUtilsObject {
    
    @Autowired
    WebDriver webDriver;
    }
```

BUT WebDriver instance could change and it won't be picked up by `SingletonUtilsObject` instance after autowiring is resolved and beans initialized.

What I was thinking is to somehow dispose @Autowired WebDriver after call and 'force' beanFactory to autowire it again on next call - just as it happens on first Bean call if it's `@Lazy`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could try to change the web driver scope to prototype and use a method in `SingletonUtilsObject` that's annotated with `@Lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prototype scope - if you want to get a new instance every time you call for getInstance.
2. Request scope if you are using HTTP requests and you need an instance for each request.

You can refer to: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes